# Are wormholes optical in nature?

Tags: optics, wormholes

What is the trending belief in wormholes? Do physicists believe they are optical in nature? Maybe created with photons? Or part of electromagnetism?

Comment: Welcome *New contributor* Wormhole!  I've downvoted your question that it does not *show* any research effort.  I've also voted to close your question for the reason that is *unclear what you're asking*.  You might find the following link helpful:  [How do I ask a good question?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: If they exist, they are gravitational in nature.

Comment: DUDE, I found the problem, I had the site locked down so the public cannot read my posts. Get back to me here or at groschen@hotmail.com if you still can't read/see it, K?

Comment: I made this post about wormholes to get response from people who can tell me what I saw. I believe it was a wormhole and its optical because it was made of photons. THIS COULD BE BIG! Rally big. If I witnessed a UFO go into a wormhole, why not put it up on a physics site? Pleas tell be how I can help others who work on wormholes? Go to here; https://www.facebook.com/ray.groschen When I saw it I filed a MUFON (mutual UFO network) report. They did nothing with it. I put the report and the image of what I witnessed up on facebook. please go to it and see what you think, PLEASE???

Answer (score 1):

Well wormholes are gravitational in nature and come from theoretic analysis of general relativity, so no to all of your questions, really. Although it is a bit unclear as to what you mean.

Comment: I'm a astro-photographer/amateur astronomer. I was out looking through my binoculars and something happened. The reason I asked if wormholes are optical in nature, at least theoretically, is I witnessed one. A wormhole. It was a cone or funnel shape but had no depth, approx 2.5 - 3 degrees titled from my line of sight which allowed me to see down it. Saw star-like object enter and WH closed down from outer edge. I have an image & more details of what happened, what was this bright boiling light bubbles please help at groschen@hotmail.com can anyone tell me what this thing was please?

Comment: @Wormhole I’m gonna have to press x to doubt there tbh. I highly, highly, doubt that was a wormhole. Can you send a link of the picture?

Comment: I just added it to my Facebook page. https://www.facebook.com/ray.groschen

Comment: @Wormhole I don't see any wormhole pictures on that facebook link? You don't even have any pictures from this year. Are you messing with me?

Comment: Nope, I am surely NOT messing with you. I have had comments about what I put up from other people so I know at least someone is seeing it. I put up what I reported to MUFON mutual ufo network and the pic. If U cant see it or read it do you just want to send me your email address? I know I know, I'm a very private person too. I don't give out my main email to anyone and have 2 gmail accounts for things like this. Or can you search for Ray Groschen? Shows me and my African American bride. RU sure Ur on my site? Its up there just for you. I never wanted anyone else to know.

Comment: maybe I got the settings blocked. send me a friend request and i'll ok it so you can see it. THIS IS NOT A SCAM. I've been sending this to as many astrophysicists and cosmologists as I can find who works in or with wormholes.

Comment: Did you see the image I made and read what I witnessed? Please tell me if this was not a wormhole opening up, taking a ship though it and then closing down what the heck could it be then?

Comment: @Wormhole Ok, i sent a friend request, i’m Thatpotato isaspy

Comment: @Wormhole Haven’t seen the image yet but if you can send me it on facebook or something that would be good.

Comment: I sent a friends request back to you. question; if in fact this is a wormhole, being the discoverer of it, does this mean I can name it?

Comment: sorry, the post with image was for friends only but i just switched it for public viewing

Comment: @Wormhole No not necessarily. Sometimes names just catch on. Again though, i am skeptical.

Comment: Did U go 2 FB? What did you think? Is this NOT a wormhole I witnessed? Do you know anyone, a professor of physics I can send the link to? Dude, this could be really BIG!! People need to know, don't ya think? How can I propose this to this group? Anything will help me, please... Ray oh and Thanks for taking the time, I really do appreciate you Thatpotatoisaspy

Comment: @Wormhole I don’t know any proffessors sorry. I commented on your facebooky post. Basically i do not think it is a wormhole. And thanks Ray, you seem like a nice guy.

Comment: Thanks and you seem like a very nice guy too.

Comment: The tools of transformation optics were readily taken from those of Einstein’s theory of general relativity, where gravitational fields actually induce a warping and distortion of space and time.  
In 2007, the most spectacular of these possibilities was proposed* by a group of researchers in U.S.They suggested that it is possible to use transformation optics to design an optical wormhole — a tunnel for light between points in space! Such as wormholes - Einstein-Rosen bridges would provide a hidden tunnel for light that allows it to travel from one region to another. SEE? It is possible dude!